# How to modify angular $http.get().then response invalid JSON to valid JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-scope, typehead

We need to implement type ahead functionality in inbox box ,but when we got response from $http get is invalid JSON so that i cant able do that.

below method i am using for view level

```
uib-typeahead="name for name in collections ($viewValue)"
```

**Angular:**

```
$scope.collections = function(val) {
                    return $http.get('/Documents/DocumentsList/', {
                        params : {
                            stk : val
                        }
                    }).then(
                            function(response) {
                                if (response.data.suggestions) {
                                    $("[uib-typeahead-popup].dropdown-menu").css('display','block');
                                    return response.data.suggestions
                                            .map(function(item) {
                                                return item.term;
                                            });
                                };
                            });
                };
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{} && {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 31,
    "city": "New York"
}
```

How to modify the invalid JSON to valid JSON and pass the valid response in then.

Comment: Why don't you fix the actual endpoint response so it is valid JSON?

Comment: Not seeing `suggestions` in your JSON response there. How do you expect it to work at all?

Comment: @Phil : yes u are right. provided json is not actula response JSON its only sample format

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to fix the problem at the source but, if you can't do that, implement your own response transformer

```
return $http.get('/Documents/DocumentsList/', {
    params: { stk: val },
    transformResponse: function(data) {
        return angular.fromJson(data.substring(6));
    }
})...
```